# How to display ASCII of alphabet , numbers and special characters on console?

Tags: c++

I tried

```
char c='A';
cout<<(int)c;
```

But this is not for special characters and numbers I think. What's should I do?

Comment: *"But this is not for special characters and numbers I think"* why not? As long as you specify them correctly (especially numbers, like `'2'`, not `2`) you should be fine.

Comment: You might want to read a little more about [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: If you want to display the character, use `cout << c;`. If you want ASCII code, then use `cout << +c;`

Comment: Oh, and in C++ you should never use C-style casting (like `(int) c`). Always look at C-style casting as a red flag that you're doing something wrong. Instead use one of the C++ cast-operators, like [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), as in `static_cast<int>(c)`.

Answer (score 1):

This will kinda do it:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i,++c)
        std::cout << c << " = " << i << std::endl;
// or:  std::cout << c << " = " << static_cast<int>(c) << std::endl;
}
```

But really, it is easier (and better) to just go look at http://www.asciitable.com/ or a similar site, because everything below 32 is not printable.

Also note, only the first 127 characters are ASCII - above that we run into extended ASCII that depends on your console settings.

Comment: Don't forget that there exists alternative to ascii as [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) ;-)